# Error al usar JSON en Input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hice mi validación de nombre de usuario en JSON & Ajax, el problema que tengo es que al estar vacío el input `#username` me da error en la consola. Lo que intentaba hacer es que al estar vacío el `input` oculte el texto del `<span>` pero no tuve éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
// Ajax code
$(function() {

    $('#username').on('keyup', function() {
        var username = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
          url: '/templates/new/includes/ajaxrequest/register.php',
          method: 'get',
          data: {username: username},
          success: function(response){
            //const json =  JSON.stringify(response)
              response = JSON.parse(response);

              if(response.status == 'error'){
                $('span').text('Ups... El nombre de usuario está en uso.');
              }
              else{
              $('span').text('El nombre de usuario está disponible.');
              }
                  // Si el input está vacío, el contenido de <span> desaparece.
              console.log(response);
          }
        });
    });
});

// PHP code
    if(!empty($_GET['username'])){
        $username = $_GET['username'];

        $check = $dbh->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $check->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $check->execute();

        if($check->rowCount() > 0){
            echo json_encode(['status'=>'error']);
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode(['status'=>'success']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que chequear que el valor de `usuario` no este vacio asi:

```
$(function() {

$('#username').on('keyup', function() {
    var username = $(this).val();

    if (username != '') {
    $('span').show();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/templates/new/includes/ajaxrequest/register.php',
      method: 'get',
      data: {username: username},
      success: function(response){
        //const json =  JSON.stringify(response)
          response = JSON.parse(response);

          if(response.status == 'error'){
            $('span').text('Ups... El nombre de usuario está en uso.');
          }
          else{
          $('span').text('El nombre de usuario está disponible.');
          }
              // Si el input está vacío, el contenido de <span> desaparece.
          console.log(response);
      }
    });
    } else {
        $('span').hide()
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, tan fácil la solución y no la pensé jaja.